# Alarm Manager fails to Trigger Alarm if date is added to calender

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create the Alarms in my application using AlarmManager.

I am able to set multiple alarms, but if DATE parameter is added to Calender, the alarms are not at all triggered. Following is my code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneShotAlarm.class);
        /*Pass the task row ID as the Unique ID for Pending Intent*/
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), (int) rowid , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        long timeSet = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeSet, pendingIntent);
```

If I add the Date parameters to Calender as

```
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
```

The alarms are not triggered. I have to schedule a event at a future date. Please suggest what I am missing. Thanks for the help!!

P.S. I am taking the date and time from Date & Time dialog picker

Comment: could you please give live example like date how you want to set

Comment: Hi Pratik, As mentioned above I am adding date & time to calender using calender.add(). I need to set an alarm for a future date and time. So adding the date and time parameters to calender and then passing this to alarmManager.

Comment: what is the value of mDay, mMonth, mYear? could please write comment with value for calendar

Answer (score 1):

I have implement AlarmManager many times, Following technique will help you.

1. calculate your alarm time in milliseconds for example you want to set alarm after 10 minutes then 10*60*1000 millisecond after current time.
2. Add your calculated time in current millisecond

Example

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long fireTime = 10 * 60 * 1000;    
Intent ucintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimeAlarmReceiver.class);
ucintent.putExtra("isAlarm", true);

PendingIntent mTimeSlot = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int)fireTime , ucintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,currentTime+ fireTime, mTimeSlot);
```

Above example works perfect.

Thank You,

Comment: Thanks Ketan, I tested your method and it works great. I made a small mistake in my code. Instead of Calender.add function please use Calender.set() and the code jus works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ketan's answer is good but there is an error.

```
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long fireTime = 10 * 60 * 1000;    
    Intent ucintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimeAlarmReceiver.class);
    ucintent.putExtra("isAlarm", true);

    PendingIntent mTimeSlot = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) requestCode, ucintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,currentTime+ fireTime, mTimeSlot);
```

However you don't want "fireTime" in the PendingIntent. You should have a request code. Which is a code you create to identify your pending intents. It works in Ketan's case because he is always using the same time. But if you change the time, you will end up with two different intents.

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html